# Find closest AWS region from the client side script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a project, where I need to select the nearest S3 region from the browser. There is only a single API that is running in the Frankfurt region that can hand out tokens for all S3 regions. I cannot use latency based routes (Route53) anymore, because it will always end up in the same EC2 instance.

I have thought of the following options:

1. Ping all applicable regions (pinging the DynamoDB endpoint is pretty fast) and pick the fastest response. To avoid hick-ups, I could ping the endpoint 3 times. The problem is that a temporary hick-up chooses an S3 point that might be far away.
2. Install a t1.micro server that responds with its own region in all applicable regions. A latency based route is used to access the fastest EC2 instance. Although this should work (it worked in the past), I require a 24/7 EC2 instance that only provides the fastest region. It's too expensive for just this goal.
3. Same as option 2, but instead of a dedicated EC2 instance, I'll use a mocked API gateway that returns its own region. The problem is that API gateways are not available yet in all regions (i.e. Sao Paulo).
4. Use a single t1.micro instance and add an elastic IP for each region. NGINX can be configured to listen on the IP addresses and return another region for each address. Route53 should be configured so it has a latency-based route that resolves to each IP address. That way I can use only a single instance, but with some elastic IPs to get the result that I need.
5. Unfortunately, I cannot resolve a DNS to an IP address from within the browser. Otherwise I could have created multiple latency-based routes that route to a fictional IP address. Simply resolving the hostname would give me an IP address and tell me which region it represent.

It would be neat if AWS would provide an endpoint that could be used by clients to determine the fastest region. Anyone has another smart solution that works on scale and doesn't cost too much?

Comment: You can just pay me to use my setup that does this with EC2, I guess. :) Seriously, though, these are interesting ideas, but another problem with using API Gateway (and another of my original attempts, which involved CloudFront) is that you won't be able to configure multiple regions to respond to the same hostname -- API Gateway sits behind CloudFront, which is global.  The upcoming [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/coming-soon-lambda-at-the-edge/) service *might* provide a solution. Intuition leads me to speculate that the Lambda component may run *inside* the AWS regional AZs.

Answer (score 0):

Some other options:

- Use a single Amazon S3 region, but **use Amazon CloudFront** -- it will cache content closer to your users
- Use **Route 53 Latency-based routing** to resolve a DNS name different depending upon location. Have it resolve to different `CNAME` records, all of which point back to Frankfurt, but when you receive the requests you can determine the closest region by the domain name used to get there (confusing, eh!)
- Subscribe to a service like [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com) to determine the **geo-location** of the user.

Comment: CloudFront can only be used for static content, so that's not option for me. With CNAME based latency routing, the webserver gets the original name in the Host header instead of the resolved name, so this doesn't work. I rather don't rely on external services.

Comment: But you can configure multiple Latency-based routing entries in Route 53. It can be configured to send to different end-points (but all in the same region), and based on the endpoints you could then send a different response.

Comment: I had tried it already, but it doesn't work. I created multiple latency-based routes, where each route maps to its own CloudFront distribution that returns the region code for that latency-based route. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. All distributions should use the same FQDN and this is not allowed. A FQDN can only be used by a single CloudFront distribution (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

> **This solution works only works for non-https websites**

I have setup another solution that uses **latency-based** routing to various **DynamoDB endpoints**. All DynamoDB endpoints respond with the following response

```
healthy: dynamodb.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

Assume that the website is hosted on **example.com** and I want to be able to find the nearest region from us-east, eu-central-1, ap-southeast-1 and sa-east-1, then I create four latency based routes:

```
region.example.com CNAME dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
region.example.com CNAME dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
region.example.com CNAME dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
region.example.com CNAME dynamodb.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

When a client invokes a HTTP GET request to http://region.example.com then it gets back the healthy response with the closest region. It's pretty trivial to fetch the region from this line.

Although not the most elegant solution, it will work without additional costs and it requires only a little bit of setup.

A more major disadvantage is that you cannot use this method with https, because DynamoDB responds with an Amazon AWS certificate. Issueing http requests from an https loaded page is not allowed (mixed content).